# Points on circle equally spaced

Tags: plotting

This might be a really simple question, but how do you generate equally spaced points on a circle? I have looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePointPicking.html), have played around for ages - I am sure I am missing something very obvious :/
[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35179/how-to-draw-line-connecting-points-on-circle/35190#35190) does it, but is there anything more straightforward?

Obviously

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

plots it, and

```
cplot[m_] := g1 = (d = (q = 100;
  f = (lop = 
     Transpose[{Flatten[
        Reverse[
          Table[Gamma[y], {y, 0, q}]] /. {ComplexInfinity -> m}], 
       Flatten[Table[x^n, {n, 0, q}]]}];
    {#1*#2} & @@@ lop);
  Flatten[f];
  Total[f]);
sol = Solve[d == 0];
r = ListPlot[{{Re@x, Im@x} /. sol}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[r, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 800]);
Show[cplot[#] & /@ Range[1]]
```

is a roots example, but was after something simpler.

Comment: Hint: Divide $[0, 2\pi)$ into $n$ equal segments...

Comment: I had worked that much out ... just have a _Mathematica_ mental block :/

Comment: Many functions' roots do it - just wanted a nice simple way to do it :/

Comment: Incidentally, is there a way of curling `n` points into a circle, or any other shape without `ParametricPlot` or `PolarPlot`?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44415/5478 ;0

Comment: @Kuba, many thanks

Comment: @martin Re curling....Perhaps this could be modified: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20004/subdividing-a-polygon-equivalent-fractions/20063#20063

Comment: @ Michael - this is what I was after - many thanks for your imparting your knowledge of previous posts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather general solution to your problem. It produces a list of the coordinates of `n` regularly spaced points on a circle centered at `{cx, cy}` with radius `r`, where the initial point is rotated counterclockwise from the x-axis by `initθ` radians (defaults to 0).

```
validNum = Except[_Complex, _?NumericQ];
regSpacedPts[center : {cx : validNum, cy : validNum : 0}, r : validNum, 
             n_Integer /; n > 0, initθ : validNum] :=
  Table[center + r {Cos[# + initθ], Sin[# + initθ]} &[N[ 2 π k/n]], {k, 0, n - 1}]
```

Here is an application.

```
With[{xy = {1/4., 3/2}, r = .5, n = 5, θ = 90 °}, 
  Graphics[{Circle[xy, r], 
            PointSize[Large], Point[regSpacedPts[xy, r, n, θ]], 
            Red, Point[xy]},
    PlotRange -> {{-1/4, 3/4}, {1, 2}},
    Frame -> True,
    PlotRangePadding -> .1]]
```

[image: 5-points]

Comment: OK, this gives me loads of things to study - 'Chop`, `With` and `Except` I am still unsure of - will give them a go - again - many thanks.

Comment: @martin. `Chop` is a bit of fussiness on my part. You could probably remove it without any harm. The validNum pattern uses `Except` to exclude complex numbers from being used as arguments.

Comment: @martin. I made some corrections you will want to attend to. I removed `Chop` (really not needed) and I stopped an extra copy of first point from being generated. This code was taken from some code It wrote to generate regular polygons, which used the extra point to close the polygon, something not needed for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ListPolarPlot` you can do the following:

```
r = 1;
points = 6;
angle = 2 π / points;
Show[
    ParametricPlot[{r * Sin[x], r * Cos[x]}, {x, -π, π}],
    ListPolarPlot[Table[{angle * n, r}, {n, 1, points}], PlotStyle->{Black, PointSize[Large]}]
]
```

Comment: Great - thank you! I'm sure I will be kicking myself in a minute :/

Comment: `ListPolarPlot` - Great! :)

Comment: Is there any way of converting these points to data that a regular `ListPlot` can plot?