# Make polygon rolling along a line smoothly

Tags: graphics, geometry, animation

I'm making an animation of a polygon rolling along the X-axis, the labels should keep their orientation and float is not allowed. Now lack of transitional status, is there an simpler way to add a rolling process?
[image]
[image]

**Updated**
I thought of a way, I feel that it can be further simplified, maybe you can merge two `RotationTransform`.

```
Manipulate[Module[{pts0,angles,pts1,pts},
pts0={{0,0},{-3,0},{0,4}};
angles=({π/2,ArcTan[3/4],ArcTan[4/3]}-π);
pts1=Fold[RotationTransform[angles[[Mod[#2,3,1]]],#[[Mod[2-#2,3,1]]]]@#&,pts0,Range[n]];
pts=RotationTransform[FractionalPart[n]angles[[Mod[Ceiling[n],3,1]]],pts1[[Mod[2-Ceiling[n],3,1]]]]@pts1;
Graphics[{Polygon@pts},Axes->1,Ticks->None,ImageSize->Large,PlotRange->{{-4,22},{-1,5}}]
],{n,0,5}]
```

Previous code

```
Manipulate[Module[{pts0,pts},
pts0={{0,0},{-3,0},{0,4}};
pts=Fold[RotationTransform[({π/2,ArcTan[3/4],ArcTan[4/3]}-π)[[Mod[#2,3,1]]],#[[Mod[2-#2,3,1]]]]@#&,
  pts0,Range[n]];
Graphics[{Polygon@pts,MapThread[Text[Style[#,13],#2+0.3Normalize[#2-Mean@pts]]&,{{"C","A","B"},pts}]},
  Axes->1,Ticks->None,ImageSize->600,PlotRange->{{-4,22},{-1,5}}]
],{n,0,5}]


Manipulate[
Module[{pts0=CirclePoints[{3/2,Sqrt[3]/2},{1,4π/3},6],pts},
pts=Fold[RotationTransform[-Pi/3.,#[[Mod[#2+1,6,1]]]]@#&,pts0,Range[n]];
Graphics[{Polygon@pts,MapThread[Text[Style[#,13],#2+0.15Normalize[#2-Mean@pts]]&,
   {{"A","B","C","D","E","F"},pts}]},
  PlotRange->{{0,9},{-1,3}},Axes->1,Ticks->None,ImageSize->600]
],{n,0,6}]
```

Comment: 1) Do the labels keep their orientation? 2) Do these polygons stay strictly along this line hugging it on each step or can these polygons float?

Comment: @Syed  The labels should keep their orientation and float is not allowed.

Comment: related: [Random polyhedra walk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79546/5478)

Comment: related: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RollingPolyhedronAndCenterOfGravityPlot/

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20004/subdividing-a-polygon-equivalent-fractions/20063#20063 -- `unrollGraphics[t]` rolls (parts of) a (regular) polygon for `0 <= t < 1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Here's my version.  The code is pretty kludgy and could definitely be optimized;  there are probably several built-in functions that I could have used but didn't know about.

The basic idea is to use $\theta$, the angle of rotation of the polygon, as a continuous parameter.  This angle can be used to determine which corner of the polygon is currently being pivoted around, and where this corner is located.

**For this code to work,** the polygon's first vertex must be located at `{0,0}`, with one edge lying along the negative $x$-axis.  Moreover, its points must be given in counter-clockwise order around the polygon.  (It is always possible to specify a polygon in this way, of course.)  This code also fails on non-convex polygons, though presumably you could fix this by using the convex hull of `pts0` to determine the pivot points and distances and such.

```
pts0 = {{0, 0}, {0, 4}, {-3, 0}};

(* Find exterior angles between successive sides *)
angles = Table[VectorAngle @@ Take[Differences[RotateLeft[pts0, i - 2]], 2], {i, 1, Length[pts0]}]

(* Find side lengths *) 
sidelengths = Table[EuclideanDistance @@ Take[RotateLeft[pts0, i - 1], 2], {i, 1, Length[pts0]}]

(* Find rotation angles at which pivot corner changes, mod 2 Pi *) 
breakangles = FullSimplify[Accumulate[Prepend[angles, 0]]]

(* Find locations of each corner when it's the pivot, modulo the perimeter *)
breakdistances = Accumulate[Prepend[sidelengths, 0]]

(* Find the perimeter *)
perimeter = Last[breakdistances]

(* Create a function that determines which corner is the pivot, as a function of theta *)
pivotcorner[th_] := First[Position[Map[(Mod[th, 2 Pi] < #) &, breakangles], True]]

(* Find the pivot's location as a function of theta *)
pivotlocation[th_] := Floor[th*perimeter/(2 Pi), perimeter] +  First[Part[breakdistances, pivotcorner[th] - 1]]

(* Find locations of polygon points by translating original polygon so that pivot is at origin, rotating, and then translating resulting polygon to correct location *)
pts[th_] := RotationTransform[-th] /@ (pts0 - ConstantArray[Part[pts0, First[pivotcorner[th] - 1]], Length[pts0]])+ ConstantArray[{pivotlocation[th], 0}, Length[pts0]]

(* Render all of that in Manipulate *)
Manipulate[Graphics[{Polygon@Evaluate[pts[th]], MapThread[Text[ Style[#, 13], #2 + 0.3 Normalize[#2 - Mean@Evaluate[pts[th]]]] &, {{"C", "A", "B"}, Evaluate[pts[th]]}]}, 
  Axes -> 1, Ticks -> None, ImageSize -> 600, PlotRange -> {{-4, 22}, {-1, 5}}], 
  {th, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's start from any `RandomPolygon`

```
n = 6
p0 = RandomPolygon[{"Convex", n}][[1]]

(*make it align along x axis*)
a0 = VectorAngle[{1, 0}, p0[[2]]];
rot = RotationTransform[-a0, p0[[1]]];
p0 = Map[rot, p0];
a = PolygonAngle[Polygon[p0], "Exterior"];
Graphics[{Polygon[p0], 
Text[Style[#, Red, 14], p0[[#]]] & /@ Range[n]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Now create intermediate steps such that after `nr` steps one side lies flat on ground.

```
nr = 5;(*intermediate steps between two flat configuration*)
ps = Join[{p0}, Flatten[Table[
     o1 = p0[[Mod[i, n] + 1]]; a1 = -a[[Mod[i + 2, n] + 1]];
     p1 = Table[ rot = RotationTransform[a1 j/nr, o1];
     Map[rot, p0], {j, nr}];
     p0 = p1[[-1]]; p1, {i, 4}], 1]];
np = Length[ps]

ListAnimate[ Table[Graphics[{Gray, Polygon[ps[[i]]], 
Text[Style[#, Red, 14], ps[[i, #]]] & /@ Range[n], Opacity[0.1], 
Polygon[#] & /@ ps}, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3.0}, {-0.25, 1.25}}, 
AspectRatio -> 1.5/3.5, ImageSize -> 500], {i, np}]]
```

[image]